# Number input type too small

Tags: html, numbers

i have problem in input type number in html5, look at to my picture, in other browser that work fine for me but in firefox, the spinner is too small. Is there a generally way to make it better?
[image]

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear what you want, please explain better.

Comment: Hey max, why you edited my question? My question in icon spinner only. No matter for the value 0 or 1. Thank you

Comment: @Max ironic comment since your comment is full of spelling mistakes !

Comment: @PaulTaylor indeed :$

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the spinner on Firefox by adding following CSS rule

```
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

There is no way to change its appearance. Please note that the ***input validation*** still works.

On Firefox 48.0.1, it appears like this:
[image: Appearance of input type number on Firefox 48.0.1]

Please update your Firefox to latest version.

Comment: It may have been fine on Firefox 48, but on 66 and 67 it's broken again