# Numeric Input control's up/down buttons too small on tablets with Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, tablet

I have an `input type="number"` control in a `table` `td` element.

```
<td>
<input name="1_DISC_NO" id="1_DISC_NO" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
</td>
```

It looks okay on PC in tablet mode (using Firefox) but its a bit difficult to click on when using touch screen instead of mouse. So I zoomed in but the up/down buttons dont get any larger.

This is a problem when using PC as a tablet, such as Lenovo Yoga

(Not a problem when using phone because they just don't display the up/down buttons at all, instead when go to type the virtual keyboard comes up as numeric keypad only)

I found this question

[Number input type too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384042/number-input-type-too-small)

but this refers to an old version of Firefox and up/down buttons looking incorrect to start with. In my case they look okay to start with and Im using latest version of Firefox.

However this did prompt me to try Chrome and that worked okay, so I assume this is a bug in Firefox ?